# Обработка списка ArrayList Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Есть список:

```
List list = new ArrayList<>();
```

В этом списке по порядку находятся следующие значения:

```
"text1"
"text2"
"http://www...."
"text3"
"text4"
"text5"
"http://www...."
"text6"
```

Как мне переделать этот список так, чтобы он имел следующие элементы (как бы все элементы между `URL` адресами должны стать одним элементом):

```
"text1+text2"
"http://www...."
"text3+text4+text5"
"http://www...."
"text6"
```

Что-то не могу логически сообразить, как сделать маленький компактный код для этой задачи. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявляя нетипизированную коллекцию:

```
List list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Вы можете получить ошибки в дальнейшем. Всегда явно указывайте тип:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Самый примитивный вариант:

```
private List<String> transform(List<String> stringList) {
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : stringList) {
        if (!s.startsWith("http://www")) {
            stringBuilder.append(s);
            stringBuilder.append("+");
        }  else if (stringBuilder.length() > 0) {
            stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
            resultList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            resultList.add(s);
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        }
    }

    if (stringBuilder.length() > 0) {
        stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        resultList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

PS. Без оптимизации и обработки граничных случаев.